# C# Получение значения из List

Tags: c#

Привет, друзья. 
Надеюсь Вы мне поможете, потому что я только начинающий в C#.

Вот тут я добавляю в свой List данные:

```
CharacterController.cs
public class CharacterController
{
List<Character> Characters = new List<Character>();
  foreach (var character in characters)
  {
    Characters.Add(new Character
      {
        Name = character.Name,
        Surname = character.Surname,
        RegistrationIp = character.RegistrationIp,
        CurrentIp = character.CurrentIp,
        RegistrationDate = character.RegistrationDate,
        LastLoginDate = character.LastLoginDate
      }
    );
  }
```

Если я вызываю в этом же файле, то всё работает.

```
Console.WriteLine(Characters[0].Name + Characters[0].Surname);
```

Но если я вызываю в другом файле, то пишет ошибку.

```
Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта.
```

Вызываю в другом файле я так:

```
Console.WriteLine(CharacterController.Characters[0].Name + CharacterController.Characters[0].Surname);
```

Полный код класса `CharacterController`:

```
public class CharacterController
{
public static List<Character> Characters { get; set; }

public static async Task LoadCharacterData(Client player)
{
  var filter = new BsonDocument("SocialClubName", player.socialClubName);
  var characters = await DatabaseManager.Characters.Find(filter).ToListAsync();

  List<Character> Characters = new List<Character>();
  foreach (var character in characters)
  {
    Characters.Add(new Character
      {
        Name = character.Name,
        Surname = character.Surname,
        RegistrationIp = character.RegistrationIp,
        CurrentIp = character.CurrentIp,
        RegistrationDate = character.RegistrationDate,
        LastLoginDate = character.LastLoginDate
      }
    );
  }

  Console.WriteLine("TEST: " + Characters[0].Name + Characters[0].Surname);
}
```

Comment: Это не может работать и в первом файле. Это весь код?

Answer (score 0):

Что бы работал твой вариант:

```
public class CharacterController
{
    public static List<Character> Characters = new List<Character>();
    ...
}
```